# Nullable int parameter to ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to pass `DbNull.Value` as parameter if the parameter is null.

```
int? param1;

DbProvider.ExecuteNonQuery("myStoredProcedure", param1);
```

I tried using something like

```
param1 = param1 == null ? DbNull.Value : param1;
```

But this conversion is not valid.

Comment: You'd need something like `DbProvider.ExecuteNonQuery("myStoredProcedure", ((object)param1) ?? (object)DbNull.Value);`

Comment: @Rob, thanks. That worked. Please put that as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result to an `int?` variable, and `DbNull.Value` is not. Try not assigning it to an `int?`:

```
int? param1;
DbProvider.ExecuteNonQuery("myStoredProcedure", param1 == null ? DbNull.Value : param1);
```

Or assigning it to an `object`:

```
object par = param1 == null ? DbNull.Value : param1;
DbProvider.ExecuteNonQuery("myStoredProcedure", par);
```